# Unable to use bidaf model without using 'cuda_device' : bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, cuda_device=-1)

Tags: python, nlp, nvidia, torch

I am trying to use bidaf question answer model
source from : https://github.com/allenai/bi-att-flow

This class is created to use the library provided by https://github.com/allenai.

```
## REQUIRES python3.6

from allennlp.common.util import sanitize
from allennlp.models.archival import load_archive
from allennlp.service.predictors import Predictor
import sys

class BidafQA:
    def __init__(self):
        # required only first time, is cached
        self.archive_file = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/bidaf-model-2017.09.15-charpad.tar.gz"
        self.archive = load_archive(self.archive_file)
        self.bidafPredictor = Predictor.from_archive(self.archive, 'machine-comprehension')

    def get_answer(self, question_text, passage_text):
        out = self.get_output(question_text, passage_text)
        return out['best_span_str'], max(out['span_start_probs']), max(out['span_end_probs'])

    def get_output(self, question_text, passage_text):
        inst = self.bidafPredictor._dataset_reader.text_to_instance(question_text, passage_text)
        outputs = self.bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, cuda_device=-1)
        out = sanitize(outputs)
        return out

    def get_probs(self, question_text, passage_text):
        out = self.get_output(question_text, passage_text)
        return max(out['span_start_probs']), max(out['span_end_probs'])

    def answerAll(self, paras_text, question):
        ans_all = list(map(lambda x: (self.get_answer(question, x[0])[0], x[0], x[1]), paras_text))
        _, probS, probE = self.get_answer(question, paras_text[0][0])
        return ans_all, (probS, probE)

    def getSRL(sent):
        # Check out 
        # https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/f700584ed1b72ab45215e405ed0d22564938d1cb/allennlp/service/predictors/semantic_role_labeler.py
        archive_file = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/srl-model-2017.09.05.tar.gz"
        archive = load_archive(archive_file)
        srlPred = Predictor.from_archive(archive, 'semantic-role-labeling')
        return srlPred.predict_json({"sentence": sent})

bidaf_obj = BidafQA()
print(bidaf_obj.get_answer("question_text", "passage_text"))
```

When the argument in self.bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, cuda_device=-1) for cuda_device is given -1 the error occurs as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bidafqa.py", line 24, in get_answer
    out = self.get_output(question_text, passage_text)
  File "bidafqa.py", line 29, in get_output
    outputs = self.bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, -1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/models/model.py", line 112, in forward_on_instance
    return self.forward_on_instances([instance], cuda_device)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/models/model.py", line 131, in forward_on_instances
    outputs = self.decode(self(**model_input))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 224, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/models/reading_comprehension/bidaf.py", line 202, in forward
    passage_question_attention = util.last_dim_softmax(passage_question_similarity, question_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/nn/util.py", line 302, in last_dim_softmax
    return _last_dimension_applicator(masked_softmax, tensor, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/nn/util.py", line 292, in _last_dimension_applicator
    reshaped_result = function_to_apply(reshaped_tensor, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/nn/util.py", line 124, in masked_softmax
    result = torch.nn.functional.softmax(vector * mask, dim=-1)
TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dim'
```

and when it is used with some number then the error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bidafqa.py", line 51, in <module>
    print (bidaf_obj.get_answer("question_text", "passage_text"))
  File "bidafqa.py", line 24, in get_answer
    out = self.get_output(question_text, passage_text)
  File "bidafqa.py", line 29, in get_output
    outputs = self.bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/models/model.py", line 112, in forward_on_instance
    return self.forward_on_instances([instance], cuda_device)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/models/model.py", line 130, in forward_on_instances
    model_input = dataset.as_tensor_dict(cuda_device=cuda_device, for_training=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/data/dataset.py", line 161, in as_tensor_dict
    for field, tensors in instance.as_tensor_dict(lengths_to_use, cuda_device, for_training).items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/data/instance.py", line 71, in as_tensor_dict
    for_training=for_training)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/data/fields/text_field.py", line 119, in as_tensor
    tensors[indexer_name] = tensor if cuda_device == -1 else tensor.cuda(cuda_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py", line 279, in cuda
    return CudaTransfer.apply(self, device_id, async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/_functions/tensor.py", line 149, in forward
    return i.cuda(device_id, async=async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 58, in _cuda
    with torch.cuda.device(device):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 125, in __enter__
    _lazy_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 84, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 58, in _check_driver
    http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx""")
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

If I don't want to use any cuda device then how am I supposed to use this command (self.bidafPredictor._model.forward_on_instance(inst, 0)) and what should be the parameter value to do so?

Comment: Despite what you might think, this question is about the python framework and its internals, and is not a CUDA. programming question. For that reason I have removed the CUDA tag. Please do not re-add it.

Comment: Ok but the main problem is of cuda only. I dont know how to remove its usage

Comment: That has everything to do with the framework and nothing to do with CUDA especially when you don't even have a driver installed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing cuda dependency of code(from each file in the allennlp library).